# Comment: I don't know, but this resource might be useful?

Tags: discussion, comments

A lot of the time I find questions that I don't know the answer to. Sometimes, I have a small piece of advice or can find some related resource that might assist the asker with their problem.

> I don't know, but this resource might be useful: http://www.example.com/

Is this an appropriate comment? I think it is because it can help the asker or any future visitors to the site. On the other hand, it might be unhelpful or at worst irrelevant to the actual question.

Comment: If you believe it's relevant and can possibly be helpful then sure it's a great use of the comment section. Even if it doesn't solve the problem (then it would be an answer) but points them in the right direction, adds some value to the post, or in any other way is helpful and relevant then go for it. Now, if they are asking how to peel a banana but you post a link on how to peel an apple, then probably not relevant.

Answer (score 11):

That's perfectly acceptable, and that's one of the main reasons to use comments (instead of answers, which *would* get deleted).